# Append a data frame to a master data frame if some columns are common

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, append

I want to append one data frame to another (the master one). The problem is that only subset of their columns are common. Also, the order of their columns might be different.

**Master dataframe:**

```
   a b  c
r1 1 2 -2
r2 2 4 -4
r3 3 6 -6
r4 4 8 -8
```

**New dataframe:**

```
      d  a   c
r1 -120 10 -20
r2 -140 20 -40
```

**Expected result:**

```
    a   b    c
r1  1   2   -2
r2  2   4   -4
r3  3   6   -6
r4  4   8   -8
r5 10 NaN  -20
r6 20 NaN  -40
```

Is there any smart way of doing this? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16674377/combine-two-dataframes-in-r-based-on-common-columns) is a similar question but the setup is different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the `bind_rows` function in the `dplyr` package. It will do some nice things for you by default, such as filling in columns that exist in one `data.frame` but not the other with `NA`s instead of just failing. Here is an example:

```
# Use the dplyr package for binding rows and for selecting columns
library(dplyr)

# Generate some example data
a <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10))
b <- data.frame(a = rnorm(5), c = rnorm(5))

# Stack data frames
bind_rows(a, b)

Source: local data frame [15 x 3]

            a          b          c
1   2.2891895  0.1940835         NA
2   0.7620825 -0.2441634         NA
3   1.8289665  1.5280338         NA
4  -0.9851729 -0.7187585         NA
5   1.5829853  1.6609695         NA
6   0.9231296  1.8052112         NA
7  -0.5801230 -0.6928449         NA
8   0.2033514 -0.6673596         NA
9  -0.8576628  0.5163021         NA
10  0.6296633 -1.2445280         NA
11  2.1693068         NA -0.2556584
12 -0.1048966         NA -0.3132198
13  0.2673514         NA -1.1181995
14  1.0937759         NA -2.5750115
15 -0.8147180         NA -1.5525338
```

To solve the problem in your question, you would want to select for the columns in your master `data.frame` first. If `a` is the master `data.frame`, and `b` contains data that you want to add, you can use the `select` function from `dplyr` to get the columns that you need first.

```
# Select all columns in b with the same names as in master data, a
# Use select_() instead of select() to do standard evaluation.
b <- select_(b, names(a))

# Combine
bind_rows(a, b)

Source: local data frame [15 x 2]

            a          b
1   2.2891895  0.1940835
2   0.7620825 -0.2441634
3   1.8289665  1.5280338
4  -0.9851729 -0.7187585
5   1.5829853  1.6609695
6   0.9231296  1.8052112
7  -0.5801230 -0.6928449
8   0.2033514 -0.6673596
9  -0.8576628  0.5163021
10  0.6296633 -1.2445280
11  2.1693068         NA
12 -0.1048966         NA
13  0.2673514         NA
14  1.0937759         NA
15 -0.8147180         NA
```

Comment: I use R version 3.4.4 and found that `select_()` is deprecated. Normal `select()` does not produce wanted result.

Comment: @vtenhunen The `dplyr` api has changed since my answer was posted. You can check out the details [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html). In short, instead of `select_()`, try `select(..., !! var)` where `var` is a variable containing column names.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
library(plyr) # thanks to comment @ialm
df <- data.frame(a=1:4,b=seq(2,8,2),c=seq(-2,-8,-2))
new <- data.frame(d=c(-120,-140),a=c(10,20),c=c(-20,40))

# we use %in% to pull the columns that are the same in the master
# then we use rbind.fill to put in this dataframe below the master
# filling any missing data with NA values
res <- rbind.fill(df,new[,colnames(new) %in% colnames(df)])

> res
   a  b   c
1  1  2  -2
2  2  4  -4
3  3  6  -6
4  4  8  -8
5 10 NA -20
6 20 NA  40
```

Answer (score 2):

The `dplyr`- and `plyr`-based solutions posted here are very natural for this task using `bind_rows` and `rbind.fill`, respectively, though it is also possible as a one-liner in base R. Basically I would loop through the names of the first data frame, grabbing the corresponding column of the second data frame if it's there or otherwise returning all `NaN` values.

```
rbind(A, sapply(names(A), function(x) if (x %in% names(B)) B[,x] else rep(NaN, nrow(B))))
#     a   b   c
# r1  1   2  -2
# r2  2   4  -4
# r3  3   6  -6
# r4  4   8  -8
# 5  10 NaN -20
# 6  20 NaN -40
```

Answer (score 1):

another option is using rbind.fill from the plyr package

## bring in your sample data

```
toread <- "
a b  c
1 2 -2
2 4 -4
3 6 -6
4 8 -8"
master <- read.table(textConnection(toread), header = TRUE) 
toread <- "
d  a   c
-120 10 -20
-140 20 -40"
to.append <- read.table(textConnection(toread), header = TRUE)
```

## bind data

```
library(plyr)
rbind.fill(master, to.append)
```

Comment: If you're using `dplyr`, why not just use `bind_rows()`?

Comment: @ialm With more careful reading, this answer *doesn't* use any `dplyr` functions (it just loads the package). Worth noting that loading `plyr` *after* loading `dplyr` will mask `dplyr::summarize` and `dplyr::mutate` with the `plyr` versions and is not recommended.

Comment: @Gregor Yes, I see that now. And for the reasons you highlight in your comment, there is a warning issued if you load `plyr` after `dplyr`, and I believe Hadley recommends loading `plyr` before `dplyr` if you ever need to use both packages.

Comment: I did not intend to include dplyr in the answer and I removed it. Thanks for pointing out that it was not needed